# How do I use Laravel Eloquent to query an object based on an attribute/accessor condition?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

Working with the examples from the documentation, if I have a accessor attribute like this:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}"; // both are real columns
}
```

How can I run a `where` based on a computed value? Something like:

```
$user = User::where('full_name', 'John Doe');
```

It should match items where `first_name` is `John` and `last_name` is `Doe`.

Is there a way to do this or am I doing it wrong?

*Update:* I found a similar question asked for Laravel 4 and it has an answer, however it states that the filtering is applied after the query is made, which will be very inefficient. Has there been any update to this mechanism since Laravel 5?

Answer (score 1):

You can use raw where statement with CONCAT mysql function:

```
->whereRaw('CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) = "John Doe"')
```

Or just with 2 wheres:

```
->where('first_name','John')->where('last_name','Doe')
```

Comment: I suppose this is the way, but perhaps I can clean it up by making a query scope from it.

Answer (score 1):

Rafal Migda's answer is probably the most correct, but I figured out a more elegant--or should I say, Eloquent--way of doing what I wanted, utilising scopes. In my model, I put:

```
public function scopeFullName($query, $fullName)
{
    return $query->whereRaw('CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) = "' . $fullName . '"');
}
```

This will allow me to use the query scope like this:

```
$user = User::fullName('John Doe');
```

Comment: You should use `$query->whereRaw('CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) = ?', [$fullName])` to prevent SQL injections.